# Splitting array into two arrays once an certain elements values equal 20

Tags: php

I am stuck with an issue that I cannot work out how to approach. i'm hoping someone can help me solve this.

I have an array which could change depending on items in a shopping cart:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 17134
            [quantity] => 7
            [text] => 1.5
            [category_id] => 46
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1001
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 1.5
            [category_id] => 46
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 18468
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 2
            [category_id] => 40
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 156
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 1
            [category_id] => 40
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 17557
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 5
            [category_id] => 43
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 11865
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 7.5
            [category_id] => 49
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 15322
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 1
            [category_id] => 42
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 16239
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 3
            [category_id] => 42
        )

)
```

I want to split the array into two arrays by looping over array's text, but at the same time multiplying the text by its corresponding quantity until the text would equal 20. Once it equals 20, I want to split the array up, so for example the result would look something like:

Old array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 17134
            [quantity] => 7
            [text] => 1.5
            [category_id] => 46
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 1001
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 1.5
            [category_id] => 46
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 18468
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 2
            [category_id] => 40
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 156
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 1
            [category_id] => 40
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 17557
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 5
            [category_id] => 43
        )

    )
```

New array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 11865
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 7.5
            [category_id] => 49
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 15322
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 1
            [category_id] => 42
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 16239
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 3
            [category_id] => 42
        )

)
```

Is this achievable?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: By "but at the same time multiplying the text by its corresponding quantity until the text would equal 20" you mean count the keys for each array item and when you reach 20 split the array?

Comment: What is the condition to achive actually is it text multiply text ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
    $i=0;
    $y=0;
    $countValue = 0;
    $newCartsArray = [];

    // $cart is your array
    foreach($cart as $index => $product):
            $countValue += $product['quantity'] * $product['text'];
            if($countValue >= 20){ // if you are sure it will always exactly reach 20 use == instead >=
                    $newCartsArray[$y] = array_slice($cart, $index-$i, $i+1);
                    $i=0;
                    $y++;
                    $countValue = 0;
            }
            $i++;
    endforeach;

    // This will add the last elements into $newCartsArray
    if($i!=1){
            $newCartsArray[$y] = array_slice($cart, count($cart)-($i-1), $i-1);
    }
```

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much for taking the time to look at this with me. The output I got was: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given. Im just trying to see why now.

Comment: Sorted! I used $newCartsArray[$y] = array_slice. Thank you so much again for looking at this. You're the best.